# Visual Studio + Xamarin: Create database SQLite

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.android

I'm trying create a database on my application (Xamarin.Android). I'm using this tutorial
http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/

but the site don't explicate about parameter to `path` on

```
private string createDatabase(string path)
{
    try
    {
        var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);{
             connection.CreateTableAsync<person>();
             return "Database created";
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me, with this parameter?

I try with "/app1/databases/dbPEduc.db" but show the Exception:

```
SQLite.SQLite3+Result.CannotOpen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net) for the Xamarin SQLite Component has an example of the correct path to use (under **Asynchronous API**)

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection (System.IO.Path.Combine (folder, "stocks.db"));
conn.CreateTableAsync<Stock>().ContinueWith (t => {
    Console.WriteLine ("Table created!");
});
```